# Eclipse/Tomcat7: application context root reloading returns 404

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, windows-8, tomcat7, eclipse-juno

I have a servlet which is mapped to application context root using the `""` string:
So when I hit the url `http://127.0.0.1:8080/myapp/`, I can see "This is ROOT!" in the browser. So far so good.

But if I modify something, say changing the String `This is ROOT!!` to `ROOT!!` and save the file in eclipse. Eclipse will take a couple of seconds to reload the context. **Now if i hit the same url, a 404 page is displayed while all other pages still work fine.** Only the root mapping is broken. So I redeploy (eclipse's "run on server") the app and the root mapping is back again. Any ideas on how can I fix this?

```
@WebServlet("")
public class Root extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.getWriter().println("This is ROOT!!");
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54955

This is a bug of tomcat 7.0.40.
when you deploy it. Context root is accessible. But reload the app will cause context root to return 404.